# How to filter with colon pattern key:value in Elasticsearch (GitHub style search)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, filter

I want to implement a filter patter in the query search term, similar to what you have in the GitHub search.

Anyone has links to documentation on how to implement that?

And how is this search pattern called? I'm having a hard time to find information about it.

For example, a search with the following text:

`country:USA type:public water`

Would filter documents that match the type and country keywords, and then do a full text search for water in the filtered results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly - you want something like Kibana Query (**KQL**) or **Lucene Query Language**.

If you use elasticsearch - its already build in. You just need to pass correct query.

```
"query": {
"query_string": {
  "query": "(content:this OR name:this) AND (content:that OR name:that)"
}
}
```

Take a look at this documentation. Pretty much sure, that you don`t need to implement something, just use existing functionality)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html